# Sheet Deactivate get sheet name/Excel.Worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm working on a VSTO addin, and I want to update a Ribbon button label to the sheet name on sheetDeactivate (a go back to functionality). The problem is, the syntax I'm using sends out the Sh variable as Object, not as Excel.Worksheet, so I could not find a way to extract sheet information from it (name).
Please tell me if I'm using the correct syntax, and if I am, how can I convert the Sh object to an Excel.worksheet.

```
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        //KEEP THEM IN CHRONOLOGICAL ORDER   
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {           
            this.Application.SheetDeactivate += new Excel.AppEvents_SheetDeactivateEventHandler (ShDeactivate);
        }

        private void ShDeactivate(object Sh)
        {
            clsSheets.Ribbon_updateBackSheet(Sh);            
        }
```

Comment: Please add vsto related tags so that relevant personnel can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Sh-object is either a chart or a workbook object (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sheetdeactivate) you should be able to just use `Sh.Name` to get the name of the object.